# How to take user input during a thread sleep?

Tags: java, multithreading, delay

I've got a method that will delay the current thread for a specified amount of time which works as intended. The problem is i want to be able tot are user input during that delay so that if the user input during the delay is "save game" then a method will call and the program will end. How would i go about doing this. My current method for the delay is:

```
public void delay()  throws InterruptedException, IOException {

    try {
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(6000);               
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

Comment: sleep=really do nothing. You will have to add an event listener and handle the save event separate. You can then also interrupt this thread from the listener and end the sleep if required.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve with the sleep. I guess you should use a [game loop](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html). There are also java game libraries around which could help you a lot there.

Comment: A friend taught me: if you are using sleep(), you are doing it wrong. Whatever the reason you are using sleep(), you can do it better without sleeping